# В каком файле разместить *=require rouge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я использую гем rouge в rails приложении для подсветки кода на странице. Когда я добавляю
*=require rouge в  assets/builds/application.css  то код подсвечивается,но после перезапуска сервера *=require rouge удаляется автоматически. Я пробовал создавать файлы application.css и application.scss в  stylesheets/ и добавлять код туда но это не работает, код не подсвечивается. Подскажите решение этой проблемы

Comment: Я решил эту проблему. Добавил <%= stylesheet_link_tag "rouge", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %> в application.html.erb. В manifest.js добавил //= link rouge.css